# Total energy of a digital filter's output from the current state

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters, signal-energy

Let's say I've been feeding some digital IIR filter input samples $x[n]$ to get output samples $y[n]$.

If after some time $t$ the input becomes all 0s, i.e.

$$x[n] = 0, \; \;  \forall n ≥ t$$

How can I find the total output energy from that point onwards (without just running the filter for ages):

$$\sum_{n =t}^\infty \left|y[n]\right|^2$$

Are there filter architectures where this is easier?  (e.g. if you factorise a filter into parallel sums of complex 1-pole filters, that's not too bad, but the factorising itself is awkward)

The filter could be real-only, or be phrased as a series of biquads - whatever's easiest to solve this problem, really.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I find the total output energy from that point onwards (without just running the filter for ages)

The output will be the sum of one or more decaying* complex exponentials -- or exponentially decaying sinusoids if you want to keep the output real.  The modes would always be the same -- i.e., the filter output would always be the sum
$$y_k = \sum_n A_n d_n^k \tag 1$$

where the $d_n$ are the modes (or poles -- take your pick) of the filter, and the $A_n$ are determined by the filter state at the point where $x_k$ goes to and stays at zero.

Because the modes of the filter are not orthogonal functions of one another, you would need to calculate

$$W = \sum_{k=k_0}^\infty \left | \sum_n A_n d_n^k \right | ^2 \tag 2$$

Because that inner sum is squared, the energy left in the filter is not going to automatically be a weighted sum of the squares of the states.

You could put an upper bound on the energy (and make the calculation much easier) by taking the magnitude inside the second summation:

$$W \le \sum_{k=k_0}^\infty \sum_n \left | A_n d_n^k \right | ^2 \tag 3$$
and simplifying:

$$W \le \sum_n \left | A_n \right |^2 \sum_{k=k_0}^\infty \left | d_n^k \right | ^2 = \sum_n \frac{\left | A_n d_n^{k_0} \right |^2}{1 - \left | d_n \right|^2} \tag 4$$

This could, however, give an upper bound that is way higher than the actual number.

> Are there filter architectures where this is easier?

There pretty much has to be, because there is in continuous-time: if you have a physical network of lossless components that's being driven by a pure voltage or a pure current source, and which drives a pure impedance, then when the input goes to zero you can make the purely physical argument that the only energy that's going to come *out* of the filter is going to be the energy that's *already in it*.

So at the point where the input goes to zero, you can just the sum of the energies in each component and know that will be the total energy of the output.

Moreover, if the filter contains dissipative components and/or has a source with a finite and nonzero impedance, then the energy that comes out of the output will always be less than the total energy stored in the elements -- so you can find an upper bound at the point that the input goes to zero.

But I don't know how to construct an analog to such a filter in discrete-time (and it may be that it is not possible, or not practical).  So this will have to remain a partial answer.

---

* at least if it's a *stable* filter

Comment: Thanks!  I think that in (2) if the components might be complex then the inner sum gets multiplied by its conjugate instead of squared.

Comment: But that's also a really interesting argument about the analogue filter - I might check to see if the state-variable digital ones could have a similar property.

Comment: "I think that in (2) if the components might be complex..." -- Thanks!  Fixed.

Comment: For the energy argument: would that give an energy value, or just an upper bound?

Comment: If I got my math right, (3) is the actual energy.  See (4) for a possibly insanely large upper bound.